# How to convert set of string to string so can set values to Multi Select picklist

Tags: apex, batch

Here is my use case:

I have two multi select picklist values from two objects
Pickist A : Apple, Orange
Picklist B : Apple, Orange, Banana

I did create two sets and compared two picklist values. Now I am trying to add values of Apple, Orange,Banana to Picklist A

```
Set<String> picklistC = notcommonValues;
                picklistC.addall(picklistValuesA);
                
                system.debug('Updated values' +picklistC);  (this set gave me the values I am looking at)
```

Now how can I get this comma separated values of set to be inserted to multi select picklist string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `String.join`, which unfortunately requires a conversion to a list (see this [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLyAAI)).

```
String picklistValues = String.join(new List<String>(picklistC),';');
```

Note that multi-select picklists are joined via `;`, not `,`.

Comment: yep that worked. Thank you